# Toggle functions in one function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#ShowUser').click(function(){
           $('.DivUser').toggle("fast");
        });
 });

 $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#ShowImage').click(function(){
           $('.DivImage').toggle("fast");
        });
 });

$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#ShowProfile').click(function(){
           $('.DivProfile').toggle("fast");
        });
 });


<label id="ShowUser">
<div class="ShowUser">

<label id="ShowImage">
<div class="ShowImage">

<label id="ShowProfile">
<div class="ShowProfile">
```

I want to put only in one function ,but javascript is not my strong side :) 
can someone help :)

Comment: <label id="Show1"/>
<div class="Div1" style="display:block">

Comment: Can you show us your HTML? There's might be a more efficient way to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id^="Show"]').click(function () {
        var id = this.id.match(/\d+$/);
        $('.Div' + id).toggle("fast");
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bjve3/1/)**

Comment: it work pretty good ,but if i have something like this :

<div id="ShowUser">Show1</div>


<div id="ShowImage">Show2</div>


<div class="DivUser">Show1</div>


<div class="DivImage">Show2</div>

Comment: Felix you are genius :)